# Is there a way I can save a file to the user's phone using Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to save a PDF file to the user's phone in my app using Kivy. Is there a way to access the app's file while it's being built on a phone? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can save files on iPhones, they just have to be in a special directory. How are you saving your file on desktop?

Comment: @Erik Right now I'm using the Python module Reportlab to generate the PDF and then doing canvas.save() to save the file. It works on my desktop that way but on a phone I get a permission error

Comment: I assume you have to pass a filename when saving it, right? To access the proper directory in an iPhone, prepend the inherent `user_data_dir` variable of your `App` class to your filename. For example, if you are saving to "foo.pdf", save it instead as `self.user_data_dir + "foo.pdf"` assuming that function is inside your `App` class.

Comment: Are you using IPhone or Android?

Comment: @Erik The function which does this is actually inside a Screen class. Is there a way to reference the App class? When I try to run `App.user_data_dir + filename` I get this Error: `builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'str'`

Comment: @JohnAnderson iPhone

Comment: Try `App.get_running_app()` instead of just `App`

Comment: @Erik I think that worked I'm not getting any errors anymore! But how can I see that saved file? Right now nothing happens when I click save and if I run it on desktop I can't find the file anywhere. By the way, thanks for all your help so far

Comment: On desktop, `user_data_dir` is some funky location. Try just printing out the full filename of where you saved it, or just `print(App.get_running_app().user_data_dir)` to find the folder :) You're welcome!

Comment: @Erik I printed out where the file should be and I get a precise location. So I tried to use the webbrowser module to open it but nothing happened. I suspect the phone can't find the file for some reason. Do you know if it is really saving the PDF to the device?